# Flash + Chrome = keyboard blocking?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, google-chrome

In one of my flash projects i meet an strange bug.
Flash Player in Google Chrome blocking some system keyboard shortcuts. 
For example such as **Alt+Shift** & **Ctrl+Shift** it`s an standart language layout switch bindings.

For my project it`s a very big problem, because I need multilingual user input.

Someone can help me with this problem?

Comment: I have this problem with Ctrl-T (new tab). You have to click off the flash area of the page, or on the title bar. No use to you though :P

Comment: Yep no use for me.

Also some time ago I solve an problem when Tab–key jump–out focus of the flash. I found new for me property for embed object, such as "seamlesstabbing = false". It`s blocking browser/flash Tab focus migration.

Comment: I found some breaks in keyboard blockade: Shift + Ctrl + Ctrl or Shift + Alt + Alt + Alt In such case event can pass the Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Chrome sends CTRL+A and ALT+A to Flash, so the input first selects all the text and then replaces it with the ALT+A (which is a polish letter).

The solution in Flash is to listen to the input and key events on the textfield and when you encounter alt + ctrl, simple reset the position of the cursor in the input textfield.

We used it in [MyWebzz.com - a website creator service](http://www.mywebzz.com)

The class you can use to solve this, and little bit more info on the problem can be found on our blog [About Chrome and Flash player ALT+a bug](http://blog.mywebzz.com/?p=127)

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem and reported this to Chrome. This seems like a Google Chrome bug.

Note that the problem occurs when you press [Right Alt] in some keyboard layouts (e.g. Polish).

After pressing [Right Alt] user can press [CTRL] to clear out CTRL state.